# Can I control my dreams?

Tags: dreaming

Is it possible to completely realize that I am only dreaming and to completely manage my dream?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Psychoanalysis101.org](http://psychoanalysis101.org/dreams/frequently-asked-questions/#5), it is quite rare to be able to control dreams, though apparently it can happen 9according to the article.  [Lucid dreaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucid_dream) is the term to describe when the person is aware that they are dreaming, further research and scepticism of lucid dreaming are outlined [in this section of the article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucid_dream#Research_and_clinical_applications)

Comment: I should also add, at the base of the Wikipedia article, there are dozens of links and resources about this.